# Busca em Tabela de Valores no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, algoritmo-de-busca, relacionamento, fórmula

Olá!

Estou fazendo uma tabela de custos para a minha empresa e estou precisando fazer uma busca em uma tabela de valores, mas a única forma que eu atualmente sei como fazer é através de vários SEs encadeados, o que vai dar muito trabalho, tempo e vai gerar uma dificuldade incrível de manutenção ou quando for para aumentar a tabela de valores.

De uma maneira mais simples, eu tenho o seguinte:

Tabelas Auxiliares

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela de Custos (Que relaciona os dados)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As colunas PNEU, DESENHO E LARGURA são feitas "na mão", de acordo com o que faz sentido na lógica da empresa, mas as colunas PERÍMETRO e PESO/QUILO devem ser geradas automaticamente.

1) Com poucos SEs eu consigo fazer uma formula para a coluna PERÍMETRO, o problema é que se a coluna TAMANHO, das Tabelas Auxiliares, ficar muito grande, ficará inviável fazer tudo isso apenas com Ses.

A lógica daqui é simples: Retorne o valor PERÍMETRO para um determinado valor de PNEU. As colunas TAMANHO e PNEU são as chaves.

2) O mesmo serve para a coluna PESO/QUILO. Na prática, existem várias larguras (n>10) e vários desenhos (n>15).

A lógica daqui é um caso pouco mais avançado, em relação a "1": Retorne um valor PESO/QUILO para um determinado valor de DESENHO E (operador lógico) LARGURA. 
LARGURA é a chave para o cabeçalho horizontal da tabela auxiliar e DESENHO é a chave para o cabeçalho vertical da mesma.

Eu sei fazer isso em Java, mas não sei "escrever isso em excel".

Grato!

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro usar `PROCV()`, assim:

```
=PROCV(VALOR_PROCURADO;MATRIZ;COLUNA_RESULTADO;FALSO)
```

**FALSO** ao final é para trazer o resultado da busca exata.

Outra coisa que pode te ajudar muito é usar a formatação de tabelas [pré-formatadas do Excel](http://excelguru.com.br/excel-2/tabelas/) que vai te ajudar muito.

Então sua fórmula ficaria assim:

1. Suponhamos que tenha duas aba, sendo uma com os dados (nome: dados) e outra auxiliar (nome: tabelas), para as tabelas auxiliares, então seria a fórmula abaixo na tabela dados, célula C2, ou seja, a primeira linha de dados, na coluna Perímetro:

   ```
   =PROCV($A2;tabelas!$A$2:$B$3;2;FALSO)
   ```

Pronto!

O `$` é para travar a coluna no caso.

Se usar tabelas pré-formatadas, seria bem mais fácil, pois quando adicionar novo dado em uma tabela auxiliar, não precisará alterar a fórmula. Faça alguns testes e verá!

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado Evert, funciona que é uma beleza.

Usei a tabela pre-formatada e ficou assim:

```
=PROCV($C3;Tabela4;3;FALSO)
```

Gostaria também de deixar aqui a seguinte curiosidade: E como usar a procv com duas condições?

```
{=ÍNDICE(Tabela3[Peso/Metro];CORRESP(D3&E3;Tabela3[Desenho]&Tabela3[Largura];0)}
```

Onde o valor que eu quero está na coluna Peso/Metro, d3&e3 são as condições concatenadas e serão procuradas nas colunas concatenadas desenho&largura.

Achei em: http://www.excelnaweb.com.br/2014/01/funcao-procv-com-duas-condicoes.html